# Managing state in a reactive pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, monads

I am constructing a reactive pipeline that needs to expand (`SelectMany`) and then flatten (in this case, `ToArray`) whilst maintaining access to a piece of state obtained at the beginning of the pipeline.

Here is pseudo-code for what I am attempting:

```
return Observable
    .Start(() => this.GetSearchResults(query))
    .SelectMany(results => results.Hits)     // results.Hits is a list of IDs. But there is also has a bool property that I want to keep through to the end of my pipeline
    .SelectMany(hit => GetById(hit.Id))      // asynchronously load each result
    .ToArray()                               // now need to pull all the results together into a containing data structure, and also include the bool flag from above in it
    .Select(resolvedResults => new ...);     // need access to both resolvedResults and the bool mentioned in the first comment above
```

So I'm trying to find a way to *cleanly* access some state determined at the beginning of the pipeline from the code at the end of the pipeline.

The first thing I tried was using anonymous types to bundle the `bool` with each result. This quickly got out of hand and was wasteful from a performance perspective.

The second thing I tried was using a subject as follows:

```
var state = new AsyncSubject<bool>();
return Observable
    .Start(() => this.GetSearchResults(query))
    .Do(results =>
        {
            state.OnNext(results.Flag);
            state.OnCompleted();
        }
    .SelectMany(results => results.Hits)
    .SelectMany(hit => GetById(hit.Id))
    .ToArray()
    .Zip(
        state,
        (results, state) => new ResultContainer(state, results));
```

This seems to work fine, but feels a little icky to me.

So what I'm wondering is whether there is a cleaner way to manage state in a reactive pipeline.

For reference, here is the *actual* code (rather than just pseudo-code):

```
public IObservable<ISearchResults<IContact>> Search(string query, int maximumResultCount = 100, float minimumScore = 0.1F)
{
    Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(query, nameof(query));

    var moreHitsAvailable = new AsyncSubject<bool>();

    return Observable
        .Start(
            () => this.searchIndexService.Search<IContact>(query, maximumResultCount, minimumScore),
            this.schedulerService.DataStoreScheduler)
        .Do(
            results =>
            {
                moreHitsAvailable.OnNext(results.MoreHitsAreAvailable);
                moreHitsAvailable.OnCompleted();
            })
        .SelectMany(
            results => results
                .Hits
                .Select(
                    hit => new
                    {
                        Id = hit.Id,
                        ParsedId = ContactId.Parse(hit.Id)
                    }))
        .SelectMany(
            result => this
                .GetById(result.ParsedId)
                .Select(
                    contact => new
                    {
                        Id = result.Id,
                        Contact = contact
                    }))
        .Do(
            result =>
            {
                if (result.Contact == null)
                {
                    this.logger.Warn("Failed to find contact with ID '{0}' provided by the search index. Index may be out of date.", result.Id);
                }
            })
        .Select(result => result.Contact)
        .Where(contact => contact != null)
        .ToArray()
        .Zip(
            moreHitsAvailable,
            (results, more) => new SearchResults<IContact>(more, results.ToImmutableList()))
        .PublishLast()
        .ConnectUntilCompleted();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pop out to Query Comprehension Syntax and do something like this

```
var x = from result in Observable.Start(() => this.GetSearchResults())
    let hasMore = result.MoreHitsAreAvailable
    from hit in result.Hits
    from contact in GetById(hit.Id)
    select new { hasMore , contact};
```

Over to you how to deal with the duplicate `hasMore` values. As we know it will be just the single distinct value (all `true` or all `false`) you could group by.